# How can I SELECT MAX(VALUE) from duplicate values which occur multiple time within each month?

Tags: sql

I have records for each user which occur multiple times each month. I wish to select just the highest value from the repeated values for each month for each user.

Table schema

**custacc**

```
ID | ac_no  | DODSTART   | od_limit
---+--------+------------+----------
1  | 110011 | 2019-02-10 | 200,000
2  | 110011 | 2019-02-12 | 120,000
3  | 110014 | 2019-02-10 |  70,000
4  | 110014 | 2019-02-12 |  10,000
5  | 110009 | 2019-02-10 |  30,000
```

**customer**

```
  ID | cust_no | name  | cust_type
  ---+---------+-------+----------
   1 | 110011  | Jame  | M
   2 | 110014  | Fred  | N
   3 | 110009  | Ahmed | M
```

How can I achieve this>

What I tried so far:

```
SELECT  
    custacc.ac_no, 
    custacc.od_limit, 
    custacc.DODSTART, 
    customer.name, 
    custacc.gl_no, 
    custacc.USERNAME, 
    customer.cust_type 
FROM 
    custacc 
LEFT JOIN 
    customer ON custacc.ac_no = customer.cust_no 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         MAX(DODSTART) LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
         ac_no
     FROM
         custacc
     GROUP BY 
         ac_no) s2 ON custacc.ac_no = s2.ac_no
                   AND custacc.DODSTART = s2.LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME
WHERE 
    custacc.od_limit != 0.00
```

The query doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, pls check my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to select the maximum od_limit for each ac_no?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes,  for each month.

Comment: Use `Max(od_limit)  , ac_no ,Month(DODSTART)` in the `Select`, then `Group By ac_no, Month(DODSTART)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(add columns that you need):
This is Oracle solution since you didn't mention it in your question:

```
SELECT ID,MAX(OD_LIMIT) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DODSTART)) FROM CUSTACC;
```

Comment: I need it in sql.